# What is use of <?,? > in the declaration in javafx

Tags: java, variables, javafx, declaration, tablecolumn

```
   private TableColumn<?, ?> colname;
```

I want to know what is use of this  in declaration of tablecolumn.

Comment: Parametrized with two wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the ? type is simply a wildcard. It means any class. You can read more on this at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you got this `TableColumn<?, ?>` wildcard based definition from skeleton code generated by [JavaFX SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html).  When SceneBuilder generates the code, it doesn't know the types to be applied to table columns, so it just generates wildcard types.

You should edit the the declaration to supply the appropriate types for your table column, for example `TableColumn<Person,String>`, unless you really want to use [wildcard types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), which is unlikely for this case.  In the sample I provided, `Person` is the type of each row item in a table and `String` is the type of a field of person to be represented in the table column (for example a `firstName`).